# Render full calendar scheduler on primefaces layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces, fullcalendar

I am unable to render full calendar scheduler on primefaces center layout. I have included following .js in my index.xhtml

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="fullcalendar.min.css"/>  
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="scheduler.min.css"/>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery.min.js" target="head"/>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="moment.min.js" target="head"/>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="full.min.js" target="head"/>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="scheduler.min.js" target="head"/>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="myScheduler.js" target="head"/>
```

In "myScheduler.js" I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () { // document ready

jQuery('#calendar').full({
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
```

and I am using fullcalender scheduler `<div>` under primefaces center layout in body of index.xhtml like below:

```
<p:layoutUnit position="center">
            <h:panelGroup layout="block">
                <div id='calendar'/>
            </h:panelGroup>                  
        </p:layoutUnit>
```

Comment: Where is fullcalendar's configuration code? Please provide more code.

Comment: @ChintanMirani i have edited my post. sorry for that.

Comment: adding jquery yourself should not be done when using PrimeFaces

Comment: Then should i remove jquery? if i remove this, it shows me missing jquery (jQuery not defined).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding below include in header of .xhtml:

```
h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head"/>
```